# Text-mode emulation on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, 64-bit, text-mode

In 64-bit Windows, it is no longer possible to enter hardware textmode in the terminal by hitting Alt+Enter. Is there a terminal/console software that supports *emulation* of VGA text modes?

Comment: To clarify, this would be done by a "terminal" or "console" program. Command processors have nothing to do with how they are displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a try to [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) - configurable Windows console emulator, I'm the author of it. Some user reviews on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560).

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> switch Fullscreen mode, and window state may be stored in settings (registry or xml). There are tabbar and status bar, but you may turn them off, if you dont need them. Also, you may choose any font for your pleasure.

A brief excerpt from the long list of options:

- Smooth resize, maximized and **fullscreen** window modes
- Use any font installed in the system, or copied to a folder of the program (ttf, otf, fon, bdf)
- Run selected tabs as Administrator (Vista+) or as selected user
- Windows 7 Jump lists and Progress on taskbar
- Integration with [DosBox](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/DosBox) (useful in 64bit systems to run DOS applications)
- Scrollbar initially hidden, may be revealed by mouseover or checkbox in settings
- Optional settings (e.g. pallette) for selected applications
- User friendly text and block selection (from keyboard or mouse), copy, paste, text search in console
- ANSI X3.64 and Xterm 256 color

Comment: I found ConEmu from one of your other answers, not this one, but never remembered to go back and comment. Thank you! ConEmu is an excellent piece of software that does an awful lot for making windows's command line less painful!

Comment: It does note resize text when Alt+Enter