# Program besides cmd.exe that can switch to text mode?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, software-rec, text-mode

I would like to test on my Windows 7 x64 system if [text mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mode) works [via this 'workaround'](https://superuser.com/a/314704/129520) of disabling my video card driver.

However, `cmd.exe` on x64 has **removed** support for `Alt`+`Enter` or right-click+"Full screen". This should not mean that the OS *itself* can't go in to text mode, however.

Is there another application beside `cmd.exe` that will try to switch to text mode?

**Note**: it was suggested that dosbox should switch to text mode but I believe it is not. When I go fullscreen with dosbox, I see on my other monitor in *Display/Screen Resolution* that the other screen's resolution is 640*480 (a well known [graphics mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_mode) resolution). So I'm looking for a program that can actually switch to text mode.

**edit**: I have tried this program but couldn't yet get to text mode: :)

- [FAR](http://farmanager.com/index.php?l=en) manager: I tried alt+enter, didn't work. tried menu / commands / Video mode, it only maximized the window. However, checked in task manager, it *didn't use `cmd.exe`*, it only used `conhost.exe`.
- copied a `command.com` from a 32-bit Windows 8. Supposedly these `.com`s have Alt+Enter still enabled (not sure about 8). It didn't start because 16-bit subsystem doesn't seem to be supported? (or so a dialog says)

**picture (un)related**

[image: Unsupported 16-Bit Application]

Comment: In that same [topic](http://superuser.com/a/314704/129520) it was stated some DOS video modes are not supported anymore. I know this is the case from Vista and higher (since we still support a DOS-program and can't use full-screen DOS anymore). According to [kb926657](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926657) you could try XP-drivers but of course this is not going to work in Win7 64bit. But the question is... **Why** are trying to use text-mode in Windows 64bit?? What would you use it for (if you don't have an application that supports it)?

Comment: @Rik thanks, this is not about support, rather the proposed workaround [told by avirk](http://superuser.com/questions/314675/314704#314704). (My implicit assumption was that this is officially unsupported, possibly undocumented, legacy part of Win7.) With kb926657, a different workaround, wouldn't the same work with 64bit XP drivers on Win x64? Why: I've 2 'other' and 2 productive reasons. Others are: it's fun and I explore this way. Productives: quite the personal but it makes me more productive; imitations not so. I've real text-mode apps but none that actually seem to *try* the switch on 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text-mode emulation on 64-bit Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/463513/text-mode-emulation-on-64-bit-windows)

Comment: @AndriyM no, i am interested in real text mode. *no emulation*. I know windows x64 supposedly forbids this, but since it was possible to use the text mode in WDDM even under circumstances when it was supposed to be forbidden in x32 in Vista, I want to test whether this limitation in x64 is artificial and in fact the system could actually use text-mode if anyone really tried and if one prepares the driver. if for no other, it looks like [BSOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSOD)s are some kind of text-mode.

Comment: I see. I guess I misunderstood the "Fullscreen mode" bit, thought it meant the real text mode. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not from the `cmd.exe` executable itself that support for Alt+Enter was removed, but rather from the code responsible for console windows in general. Current GPU drivers are probably not even required any more to implement the possibility to switch to text mode and back (I didn't check this myself now, but I remember having read something about that in the past).

From two articles ([#1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1243573/Vga-Text-Mode-To-Hell-and-Back), [#2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1244854/Vga-Text-Mode-To-Hell-and-Back-Part-II)) I've found on the *Code Project* web site, it looks like it is somewhat possible using obscure techniques, involving custom drivers calling the BIOS directly (which wouldn't then work on EFI-based systems which tend to be the norm nowadays).